# Boot into Windows, but limit its permissions to certain partitions

Tags: laptop, multi-boot

I have an Acer laptop. It's a low-level laptop with i5-6200U, 4GB SDRAM.

I would like to install Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on the same computer.

I would like to use Linux Ubuntu for everything and use Windows only for working and gaming.

(huge unneeded story here)

I'd like to limit Windows' permissions of the computer. For example, I would like Windows not being able to mess around with Linux' partition (such as format or even access).

Virtual machine would solve this perfectly. However my laptop doesn't support IOMMU GPU passthrough and VMs have ridiculous low performance. But it does limit hypothetical power of Windows over other partitions.

I need Windows to be able to access everything on the computer (GPU, CPU, RAM, screen, keyboard, motherboard hub) except partition with my Linux data. This cannot be an application on Windows itself, it has to be something beyond Windows' access (something like Hypervisor)

**TL;DR:** I'd like to boot into Windows, but limit its permission on the harddrive, so it cannot access, edit (or even see) other partitions.

Comment: You can't stop Windows from formatting the partition.  It doesn't understand how to read it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this to see what Linux stuff is accessible in Windows? From my experience, Windows will not show the drives in File Manager by default. Stock Windows cannot read Ext file systems. Your only worry would be a user, with admin privileges, installing something like Ext2Fsd. This would not succeed in hiding the volume completely, as it would still be visible in Disk Manager for those crafty enough to find it.

A different solution would be installing Ubuntu on a removable drive. With an aptly-sized external drive, simply removing it would allow Windows to have access *only when you want* (as the holder of the drive). If USB 3.0 ports are available, you should be able to get manageable performance from this method (definitely more so than a VM). Some motherboards have an option for selecting boot device at startup, which would make booting to Ubuntu easy, and totally invisible without the external drive. Full-disk encryption could be used to further secure the root/home partitions on the external drive from snooping via another machine.

**EDIT:** One additional consideration: **Your mileage may vary on flash-based external media (e.g., SSD).** Refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652337/why-no-swap-partitions-on-ssd-drives)
question as to why swap partitions can reduce the life of an SSD. I would not recommend running without a swap partition on a system with limited RAM. You *could* add a swap partition on the internal drive, and configure Ubuntu to swapon it at boot. This would be more accessible to Windows Disk Manager, but would require some forensics skills to collect any useful data. It is generally debated how much swap can affect the life of an SSD.

Comment: So you're recommending persistent USB installation with Ubuntu on it?

Comment: Yes, if that would be feasible for your purposes (i.e., you can carry the drive). Use the laptop to install Ubuntu on the removable media, then install Windows without the external drive attached and Windows will have total control over boot. Edit: Installing Ubuntu on another drive via Live CD - not using the Live CD exclusively (Just want to make that clear).

Comment: Maybe more off-topic question. If I boot an item (Ubuntu in this case) from my USB (using boot order) does this happen before Windows can do anything? A.k.a. does Windows have *any* influence over computer when I straight up boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: Hmm, I certainly wouldn't think so, as Windows Boot Manager will not run if you manually select the boot device. Now if you mistakenly boot into Windows with the external connected, there might be some attempt to read from that drive as Windows boots - again, it will be an Ext partition, so I don't think there will be much concern for it actually *doing* anything without considerable work to Windows. That may warrant a separate question.

Comment: The "I certainly wouldn't think so, as *Windows Boot Manager will not run if you manually select the boot device*" is more than enough. Thank you.

Comment: First, Windows doesn't generally use or access any partitions you have not assigned a drive letter to (besides its couple boot/recovery partitions), second encrypting the Linux partitions will essentially block Windows from even trying.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Encrypt the partitions used by the Linux system, and don't tell Windows how to decrypt.

This is going to be the most thorough and effective method.

**Method 2:**

Make sure no drive letters are assigned to the Linux partitions.

This is a simpler method that is likely to work just fine. Windows simple doesn't use the partitions it has not been told to use. Windows 10 will typically have 2 boot/recovery partitions, and then the data partition which will have a drive letter.